# html data in tableView, how to display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

i have a custom TableView cell class. I should display some data , that comes from server. This data comes with something like that:

```
<div><img src="/app/public/images/news/2014/02/27/inter.JPG?rand=0.26758097275160253" style="width: 470px; height: 299px;" /></div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<p class="lead">......
```

. etc.

what is the better way to display such things in tableViewCell? I think that textView is useless here..

Comment: Could you use a `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIWebView to display html, or extract what you need from the html (using a parser, or worst case a regex), and place that data in each cell.

Probably a better approach is for your server to handle the html extraction, and send you the data in json format...

Comment: thanks, but it is okay, that i put nil instead of baseUrl?[cell.web loadHTMLString:self.dataDictionaryForCurrentNews[@"body"] baseURL:Nil];